# CoreData make sections by NSNumber property works not correct

Tags: core-data

I am using CoreData fetchedResultsController on my project. I want to sort my `Event : NSManagedObject` just two sections by `isDone` property, which actually a BOOL value. When i add NSManagedObject subclass, i didn't check "Use scalar properties for primitive data types". So it's `NSNumber` type

The issue is the section names and numbers are correct. But the events in section "0" are not all `isDone = FALSE` and section "1" are not all `'isDone=YES'`, So is this possible or anything wrong on my code?

**Event.h**

```
@interface Event : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * endDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * isDone;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
end
```

**Init NSFetchedResultsController**

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"endDate" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:@"isDone"
                                                   cacheName:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

Any help? thanks!

**-------------EDIT------------------------**

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"endDate" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"isDone" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sort1,sort]];
```

Comment: You need your sort descriptors to match up with your sectionName.  Add another sortDescriptor using `isCountdown` as the key, and include this as the first item in the array of sortDescriptors.  Also you have used `isCountdown` as your sectionNameKeyPath, but use `isDone` as the property name - are these related?

Comment: Hey thanks! It works as i edit.  I just thought sectionNameKeyPath is finished sort, and then sort by "endDate".

Comment: Instead of adding that code to the question, you should move it to an answer. It answers the question, so it should be an answer.

Comment: When i try to answer my own question, stackoverflow popup a hint "edit" or "comment". Should i answer my own question?

Comment: Yes, your code actually answers the question. It's not an addition to the question or a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @pbasdf 's help, i changed my code to below. I understood when set sectionNameKeyPath aleady make a sort, but actually not. Also you can check [IOS DEV CENTER sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html). Hope helps someone.

```
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"endDate" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"isDone" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sort1,sort]];
```